# Write text in a column based on ascending dates. Pandas Python

Tags: pandas, datetime

There are three dates in a df Date column sorted in ascending order. How to write text *'Short'* for nearest date, *'Mid'* for next date, *'Long'* for the farthest date in a new column adjacent to the Date column ? i.e. 2021-04-23 = Short, 2021-05-11 = Mid and 2021-10-08 = Long.

```
data = {"product_name":["Keyboard","Mouse", "Monitor", "CPU","CPU", "Speakers"],
        "Unit_Price":[500,200, 5000.235, 10000.550, 10000.550, 250.50],
        "No_Of_Units":[5,5, 10, 20, 20, 8],
        "Available_Quantity":[5,6,10,1,3,2],
        "Date":['11-05-2021', '23-04-2021', '08-10-2021','23-04-2021', '08-10-2021','11-05-2021']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],  format = '%d-%m-%Y')
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) the dates, then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) your values in the desired order:

```
df['New'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).rank(method='dense')
               .map(dict(enumerate(['Short', 'Mid', 'Long'], start=1)))
             )
```

Output:

```
  product_name  Unit_Price  No_Of_Units  Available_Quantity       Date    New
1        Mouse     200.000            5                   6 2021-04-23  Short
3          CPU   10000.550           20                   1 2021-04-23  Short
0     Keyboard     500.000            5                   5 2021-05-11    Mid
5     Speakers     250.500            8                   2 2021-05-11    Mid
2      Monitor    5000.235           10                  10 2021-10-08   Long
4          CPU   10000.550           20                   3 2021-10-08   Long
```